# How to refresh mxGraph on window resize?

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, mxgraph

I'm trying to make mxGraph responsive and so far I have tweaked the vertexes to have dynamic width based on container size, roughly like the snippet below.

```
graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
try {
   var containerWidth = container.clientWidth;
   var itemWidth = 0.1 * containerWidth;
   var itemHeight = 40;
   var distanceWidth = itemWidth + (0.018 * containerWidth);
   var v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'Item A', 0, distanceHeight, itemWidth, itemHeight,'vertexStyle');
   var v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'Item B', distanceWidth, distanceHeight, itemWidth, itemHeight,'vertexStyle');
}
finally {
   graph.getModel().endUpdate();
}
```

This works except it needs to be refreshed upon resizing of window. I'm guessing I will need to use mxEvent to listen to the resizing of the window. However, I can't quite figure out how to do that. Has anyone done anything similar before? Any hint or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!